# Wide and high table scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a web application with a robust table which unfortunately has to be quite wide and high.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/orechova/ATKrU/17/

You can see that it is quite unconfortable to have to scroll right only to achieve the vertical scroller of the table.

It is problematic to move the scroller to the left with `direction: rtl` if a table is inside. I could have some jQuery scroller, but that wouldn't have the same design as the others. I had this idea that it would be possible to somehow scroll the table with the main scroller - the one of the browser window. Could I achieve this?

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: Does the left-side scorllbar help the design in any way? If not, convince the customer that changing around established design components is unlikely a good idea.

Comment: The table is quite wide, so he is kind of right about the design - he has to scroll right to see the scroll bar on the right side. I didn't see a problem because I simply clicked on the table and scrolled it with keyboard arrows or with touchpad, but when I think about it, the position on the right side is not quite good. I wonder why it is still not possible to set this with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've made a decision to leave it as it is for now and later rebuild the page with fixed positions for all other elements except the table, which could be then scrollable by the browser application main scroll.